# Sending similar jobs from different actors to a single router in Akka

Tags: akka

I want to make an application using Akka where different actors will be using the same router to submit their jobs.

My question is, is it possible to send similar jobs from different actors to the same router in Akka ?

Comment: It would work, but it is probably not the best decision architecture-wise.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your actors are in the same `ActorSystem`, then you should have no problems.

In this case just the actor which receives the messages will have a different `sender`.

Note that this sounds like a bad design, though. For the sake of the answer though, here is an example:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, ActorRef, Props, Actor}
import akka.routing.RoundRobinPool

class Worker extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case PowerMessage(value) =>
      sender ! ResultMessage(value * value)
  }
}

class Sender(router: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  val actorName = self.path.name

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case m @ PowerMessage(value) =>
      router ! m
    case ResultMessage(value) =>
      System.out.println(s"Sender ($actorName). Result: $value.")
  }
}

class Master(workers: Int) extends Actor {

  val router: ActorRef = context.actorOf(
    Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(workers)),
    name = "workerRouter"
  )

  val sender1 = context.actorOf(
    Props(new Sender(router)),
    name = "sender1"
  )
  val sender2 = context.actorOf(
    Props(new Sender(router)),
    name = "sender2"
  )

  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case StartCalc =>
      (1 to workers * 2).foreach {
        case index =>
          if (index % 2 == 1) {
            sender1 ! PowerMessage(index)
          } else {
            sender2 ! PowerMessage(index)
          }
      }
  }
}

object Senders {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("TestSystem")
    val master = system.actorOf(
      Props(new Master(10)),
      name = "master"
    )
    master ! StartCalc
  }
}


sealed trait MainMessage
case class PowerMessage(value: Long) extends MainMessage
case class ResultMessage(value: Long) extends MainMessage
case object StartCalc extends MainMessage
```